# ul in form not sending data to $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, post

I have a form with ul as a dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dLabel" class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Account Type
```

Doctor
            Patient

How do I send what I select in it to a **PHP** `$_POST` variable?

I tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871478/ul-in-the-form-not-sending-to-the-post) didn't work. Then, I got this form from [this bootsrap templates](http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Cardio/) signup form but I don't realy know javascript.

Here is the full form code:

```
<form action="account.php" class="popup-form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="text" name="username"  class="form-control form-white" placeholder="User Name">
    <input type="password" name="passwrd" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button id="dLabel" class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Account Type
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a class="cl" href="#">Doctor</a></li>
            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a class="cl" href="#">Patient</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-holder text-left">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredOne" name="check" />
            <label for="squaredOne"><span>I Agree to the <strong>Terms &amp; Conditions</strong></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show what you have been tried so far ?

Comment: UL are not form elements. Either you send the via GET using the links, or you create some javascript code to send a value via ajax post

Comment: i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871478/ul-in-the-form-not-sending-to-the-post this but didnt wrk

Comment: By default, `ul`s aren't posted. You need an `<select>` or a hidden input updated via `js`

Comment: You should use `form` tag with `method="post"`.Then you can use list value to use `option` tag.

Comment: Where is your form? Please post your code.

Comment: @GauravRai i have posted full form code

Comment: You need to write some javascript code. Approach could be: Add a hidden field, and onClick event for li, extract the text and insert into hidden field as mentioned referral stack link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871478/ul-in-the-form-not-sending-to-the-post . Try it and update your question.

Comment: @GauravRai i tried it but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below code i fixed the problem

```
            <form action="account.php" class="popup-form" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Full Name">
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Email Address">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="User Name">
                <input type="password" name="passwrd" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Password">
                <input class="span2" id="a_type" name="a_type" type="hidden">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button id="dLabel" class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Account Type
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                        <li onclick="$('#a_type').val('Doctor'); $('#searchForm').submit()" class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a class="cl" href="#">Doctor</a></li>
                        <li onclick="$('#a_type').val('Patient'); $('#searchForm').submit()" class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a class="cl" href="#">Patient</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-holder text-left">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredOne" name="check" />
                        <label for="squaredOne"><span>I Agree to the <strong>Terms &amp; Conditions</strong></span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit"></input>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dLabel" class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Account Type
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a class="cl" href="#">Doctor</a></li>
        <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a class="cl" href="#">Patient</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code :

```
$(".cl").click(function () {
     var val = $(this).html();
     $.post("test.php",{v:val},function (data){
       alert(data);
     });
 });
```

test.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["v"]) && $_POST["v"] != "") {
   echo $_POST["v"];
   exit;
}
?>
```

I'm assuming that your HTML and PHP files are in same folder.And you've included `jQuery` library in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` and `<li>` are not form tags that send value, you need to use `<select>` instead.

```
<select name="type">
  <option value="doctor">Doctor</option>
  <option value="patient">Patient</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i would like to keep the bootstrap template

Comment: @SebinPJohnson have a look at [bootstrap select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

In `<ul> <li>` tags you cannot select a value. If you are using any pre-defined jquery library then you can pass by post data. Else change the ul li tags to "radio buttons or checkboxes or select" according to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

In the `li` tag add an attribute. Example:

```
<li class="animated lightSpeedIn" name_pressed="Doctor"><a href="#">Doctor</a></li>
```

and I assume you have an event for clicking the the `li`. If not, you can add a class. When you click that `li` with the respective class take the attribute. In this exemple you will take the "Doctor" from `name_pressed` attribute and with an `if` redirect on the page you want.

Like this:

```
<li class="animated lightSpeedIn clickable_li" name_pressed="Doctor">Doctor</li>
```

and the javascript:

```
$(".clickable_li").click(function (e) {
    var name = $(this).attr('name_pressed');

    if (name == 'Doctor') {
        //make something
    }
});
```

Or you can add `onClick` event. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)